# Prove ◇(p ∨ q) → (◇p ∨ ◇q) and ◇(p ∧ q) → (◇p ∧ ◇q) in Modal Logic K

Tags: logic, modal-logic, proof

I would really appreciate a rundown of a proof of one of the formulas or both:

1) **◇(p ∨ q) → (◇p ∨ ◇q)**

2) **◇(p ∧ q) → (◇p ∧ ◇q)**

I'm allowed to use following proof procedures of modal logic K:

1) Tautologies of Propositional Logic PC

2) Axiom K: **◻(φ → ψ) → (◻φ → ◻ψ)**

3) Modus ponens, rule of detachment: **(p → q), p ⊢ q**

4) Godel translation G: **if φ then ◻φ**

5) **◇φ = ¬◻¬φ**

6) **if φ → ψ and ψ → ϑ then φ → ϑ**

7) **if φ → ψ then ◻φ → ◻ψ**

I managed to prove **(◇p ∨ ◇q) → ◇(p ∨ q)** but I have problems with these two formulas.

EDIT:
What I've come up with so far (there are several steps missing in the middle still):

1. **(¬p ∧ ¬q) → ¬p** (tautology of PC)
2. **(¬p ∧ ¬q) → ¬q** (tautology of PC)
3. **◻(¬p ∧ ¬q) → ◻¬p** (if φ → ψ then ◻φ → ◻ψ)
4. **◻(¬p ∧ ¬q) → ◻¬q** (if φ → ψ then ◻φ → ◻ψ)
5. **(◻(¬p ∧ ¬q) → ◻¬p) → [(◻(¬p ∧ ¬q) → ◻¬q) → (◻(¬p ∧ ¬q) → (◻¬p ∧ ◻¬q))]** (tautology of PC)
6. **(◻(¬p ∧ ¬q) → ◻¬q) → (◻(¬p ∧ ¬q) → (◻¬p ∧ ◻¬q))** (modus ponens (3, 5))
7. **◻(¬p ∧ ¬q) → (◻¬p ∧ ◻¬q)** (modus ponens (4, 6))
8. **missing steps**
9. **(◻¬p ∧ ◻¬q) → ◻¬(p ∧ q)** (THIS IS WHAT I WANT)
10. **[(◻¬p ∧ ◻¬q) → ◻¬(p ∧ q)] → [¬◻¬(p ∧ q) → ¬(◻¬p ∧ ◻¬q)]** (tautology of PC: (p → q) → (¬q → ¬p))
11. **¬◻¬(p ∧ q) → ¬(◻¬p ∧ ◻¬q)** (modus ponens (9, 10))
12. **◇(p ∧ q) → (◇p ∧ ◇q)**

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how to start. In **(◇p ∨ ◇q) → ◇(p ∨ q)** example I started with **¬(p ∨ q) → ¬p** and **¬(p ∨ q) → ¬q**.  1) **◻¬(p ∨ q) → ◻¬p**

2) **◻¬(p ∨ q) → ◻¬q**

3) **(◻¬(p ∨ q) → ◻¬p) → [(◻¬(p ∨ q) → ◻¬q) →  (◻¬(p ∨ q) → ◻¬(p ∧ q))]**

4) ... modus ponens x 2

5) **(◻¬(p ∨ q) → (◻¬p ∧ ◻¬q)) → ((¬◻¬p ∨ ¬◻¬q) → ¬◻¬(p ∨ q))**  

6) **(¬◻¬p ∨ ¬◻¬q) → ¬◻¬(p ∨ q)** 

However, I really don't know how to prove **◇(p ∨ q) → (◇p ∨ ◇q)**

Comment: Here's a hint. Assume ◇(p ∨ q), then assume ¬(◇p ∨ ◇q) and derive a contradiction. If you get a contradiction, that means that if ◇(p ∨ q) then (◇p ∨ ◇q).

Comment: @EliranH Thank you for your reply, but I'm afraid that it won't help. I'm supposed to give a direct proof based on basic tautologies like **¬(p ∨ q) → ¬p**. I might, however, understand your hint wrongly. If that's the case, could you please elaborate on how to apply your reasoning.

Comment: @Keelan I edited my original post and added what I have come up with so far, there are several steps missing in the middle still. Could you please review my proof and help me with missing steps?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I can give you a hint for a strategy, rather than a complete proof. Let's take your second proposition as the candidate for proof:

◇(p ∧ q) → (◇p ∧ ◇q)

1. Start by proving ◇(p ∧ q) → ◇p  and also  ◇(p ∧ q) → ◇q. 
   It is easy to prove the ◻ counterparts of these:  (p ∧ q) → p is a tautology of PC, so you can derive ◻((p ∧ q) → p) and hence by the K-axiom ◻(p ∧ q) → ◻p. The proof of the ◇ counterparts involves extra steps, because you need to use the equivalence of ◇φ and ¬◻¬φ and prove the contrapositive. In general, it is always the case that if φ → ψ then ◇φ → ◇ψ, though this isn't needed as a separate axiom within K, because it can be derived from the others.
2. Now that we have ◇p and ◇q we need to get to ◇p ∧ ◇q. If we were allowed to help ourselves to the rules of PC, this would be easy, because this is simply the introduction rule for ∧. But your problem specifies that we may only use the tautologies of PC, not its rules. A useful tip is that a rule of PC corresponds to a conditional tautology. So in general, if in PC we can prove ψ from φ then the material conditional φ → ψ is a tautology. So the introduction rule for ∧ implies the following is a tautology: φ → (ψ → (φ ∧ ψ)) and hence ◇p → (◇q → (◇p ∧ ◇q)).
3. You should now be able to show that ◇(p ∧ q) implies each of ◇p and ◇q and hence by transitivity that it implies ◇p ∧ ◇q.