# ◇(p ∨ q) → (◇p ∨ ◇q) in Modal Logic K

Tags: logic

I would really appreciate a full proof of this theorem ("possibly that p or q, entails that its possible that or it is possible that q").
I need to prove ◇(p ∨ q) → (◇p ∨ ◇q) in [Modal Logic K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic).
(◇p ∨ ◇q) → ◇(p ∨ q) example
I started with ¬(p ∨ q) → ¬p and ¬(p ∨ q) → ¬q.

1. ◻¬(p ∨ q) → ◻¬p
2. ◻¬(p ∨ q) → ◻¬q
3. (◻¬(p ∨ q) → ◻¬p) → [(◻¬(p ∨ q) → ◻¬q) → (◻¬(p ∨ q) → ◻¬(p ∧ q))]
4. ... modus ponens x 2
5. (◻¬(p ∨ q) → (◻¬p ∧ ◻¬q)) → ((¬◻¬p ∨ ¬◻¬q) → ¬◻¬(p ∨ q))
6. (¬◻¬p ∨ ¬◻¬q) → ¬◻¬(p ∨ q)
   However, I really don't know how to prove ◇(p ∨ q) → (◇p ∨ ◇q)

I can use this :

1. Tautologies of Propositional Logic PC
2. Axiom K: ◻(φ → ψ) → (◻φ → ◻ψ)
3. Modus ponens, rule of detachment: (p → q), p ⊢ q
4. Godel translation G: if φ then ◻φ
5. ◇φ = ¬◻¬φ
6. if φ → ψ and ψ → ϑ then φ → ϑ
7. if φ → ψ then ◻φ → ◻ψ

Comment: It depends on your book's allowed ND rules in K. Generally speaking you'd better have *derivable* rules such as ◊-elim(out) and ◊-intro(in) rules, otherwise if you depend on its definition from □ it'll be too cumbersome due to many negations. If you can use above said rules then it should be fairly easy to apply other standard PL rules to finish in a few steps within a Fitch-like nested column...

Comment: Please note that this is not a site where others will simply solve your homework. According to our guidelines, you should at least provide your own thoughts on the problem and particular points at which you have problems.

Comment: My answer to this question might help a little: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/38465/prove-p-%E2%88%A8-q-%E2%86%92-p-%E2%88%A8-q-and-p-%E2%88%A7-q-%E2%86%92-p-%E2%88%A7-q-in-modal-logic-k